# How to click the "Add friends" button on facebook with selenium python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I tried the script below but it doesn't work, I can't find any HTML at the "Add friend" button. [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/552vY.png) . Is there any way to press that button? Thank you

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Add Friend").click()
```

It shows :

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Add Friend").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: `.find_elements_by_link_text()` returns a `list`. Why do you expect calling `.click()` on it to do anything or more specifically what would you expect it to do?

Comment: what´s the use case for this? why would you automate this?

Comment: @luschn  yes , I want to automate it !

Comment: “I want to” is not an answer to the question _why_ … This can hardly have a real-world application for anyone using Facebook and this feature like it is intended to.

Comment: exactly, why would anyone want to automate this? you add friends because you know them, for example. you cannot automate this, unless you want to do something shady or randomly add people you don´t even know. there´s no point in that.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to do this. So just be aware and don't come and complain here when your account gets banned

Comment: thanks  @WizKid and  @ luschn  . I just try to know it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the xpath provided is correct, try `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add Friend").click()` instead of `driver.find_elements` as `driver.find_elements` returns a list instead of a single element and that's why it is returning an error in your case.